# Mismatched input erroron line

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have been trying to figure out this mismatched input error and i just cant seem to find it. The error is pointing to line 22
stopDistance    = strategy.position_size > 0 ? ((buyPrice - close) / close)

`

```
strategy("My strategy", 
     overlay=true, 
     initial_capital = 500, 
     default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, 
     default_qty_value = 100, 
     commission_type = strategy.commission.cash_per_contract, 
     commission_value = .005)

i_ma1         = input.int(title = "MA 1 Length", defval = 200, step = 10, group = "Strategy Parameters", tooltip = "Long-term MA")
i_ma2         = input.int(title = "MA 2 Length", defval = 10, step = 10, group = "Strategy Parameters", tooltip = "Short-term MA")
i_stopPercent = input.float(title = "Stop Loss Percent", defval = 0.10, step = 0.10, group = "Strategy Parameters", tooltip = "Failsafe Stop Loss Percent Decline")
i_startTime   = input.time(title = "Start Filter", defval = timestamp("01 Jan 1995 13:30 +0000"), group = "Time Filter", tooltip = "Start Date and Time")
i_endTime     = input.time(title = "End Filter", defval = timestamp("1 Jan 2099 19:30 +0000"), group = "Time Filter", tooltip = "End Date and Time")

ma1 = ta.sma(close, i_ma1)
ma2 = ta.sma(close, i_ma2)

f_dateFilter = time >= i_startTime and time <= i_endTime

var float buyPrice = 0
buyCondition    = close > ma1 and close < ma2 and strategy.position_size == 0 and f_dateFilter
sellCondition   = close > ma2 and strategy.position_size > 0
stopDistance    = strategy.position_size > 0 ? ((buyPrice - close) / close)
stopPrice       = strategy.position_size > 0 ? buyPrice - (buyPrice * i_stopPercent)
stopCondition   = strategy.position_size > 0 and stopDistance > i_stopPercent

if buyCondition
    strategy.entry(id="Long", direction = strategy.long)

if buyCondition[1]
    buyPrice := open

if sellCondition or stopCondition
    strategy.close(id = "Long", comment = "Exit" +(stopComdition ? "SL=True" : ""))
    buyPrice := na
```

`

I have tried searching for indentation errors but i haven't found anything

Answer (score 0):

When using ternary conditional operator, you have to specify `else` branch.

You can use `na` if you don't need it:

```
stopDistance    = strategy.position_size > 0 ? ((buyPrice - close) / close) : na
stopPrice       = strategy.position_size > 0 ? buyPrice - (buyPrice * i_stopPercent) : na
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a [ternary operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#op_%7Bquestion%7D%7Bcolon%7D). It's the same as if you'd use an if statement except that it also expects an else case expression. So in your example it should look something like this:

```
stopDistance    = strategy.position_size > 0 ? ((buyPrice - close) / close) : "missing else expression like 0 or na"
```

You'll have to fix the other occurances too.